Getting sum for each day based on most recent timestamp entry for each entity
I have a table that contains an ID, timestamp, and integer. Each row is a "snapshot" of the entity at a given time:
TableA



ID
timestamp
num




A
2024-02-04
5


B
2024-02-04
3


C
2024-02-07
8


A
2024-02-07
3



My goal is to get a table of all days from the last year and show the sum of num for that given day. The sum for each day though should look at the most recent timestamp for each entity. Then if there's no data for a given day, just forward-fill until reaching the next timestamp. So the result would be:
Goal



day
total




2024-02-04
8


2024-02-05
8


2024-02-06
8


2024-02-07
14



2024-02-05 and 2024-02-06 are filled from the most recent row because there is no timestamp data for them, and 2024-02-07 is 14 because entity A now has "3" instead of "5", and entity "C" has been added (3 + 8 + 3).
My approach has been to start with a recursive CTE for the days of the last year, and then left join on another CTE that contains the aggregated data.
WITH DateSequence AS (
  SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS [Date]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, [Date])
  FROM DateSequence
  WHERE DATEADD(DAY, -1, [Date]) > DATEADD(DAY, -365, GETDATE())
),

Aggregator AS (
  /* for each day in TableA, sum the most recent `num` columns for each entity */
)

SELECT DateSequence.[Date], Aggregator.total 
FROM DateSequence 
LEFT JOIN Aggregator ON Aggregator.date = DateSequence.[Date]
ORDER BY DateSequence.[Date]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 365);

The two parts I haven't worked out are the summing and the forward-filling. I'm pretty sure I need to use window functions, and need a way to say: for each day in TableA, sum the most recent num columns for each entity.

Your question is a little unclear. Your example TableA has the same timestamp listed for multiple rows each with different values for the num column. It looks like in your Goal example, you grouped up the rows with timestamp = '2024-02-04' but not for the rows with timestamp = '2024-02-07'. Why? Also where did you get 14 from for timestamp = '2024-02-07' in your Goal results example?

One way to  achieve this is:
First, creates the tables  (#tableA with your source , #tmpDateSequence with a list of days = 2024-02-03 ,2024-02-04 ,2024-02-05...)
drop table if exists #tmpDateSequence,#tableA;
go

CREATE TABLE #tableA
(
    id char(1),
    timestamp date,
    num int
);
INSERT INTO #tableA(id,timestamp,num)
VALUES
        ('A',   '2024-02-04',   5),
        ('B',   '2024-02-04',   3),
        ('C',   '2024-02-07',   8),
        ('A',   '2024-02-07',   3);

WITH DateSequence AS (
  SELECT CAST('2024-02-03' AS DATE) AS [Date]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
  FROM DateSequence
  WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date]) < CAST('2024-02-10' AS DATE)
)
SELECT *
INTO #tmpDateSequence
FROM DateSequence;


Next step is to generate all possible combinations between date and ids.
/*this generates all possible combinations of dates with ids*/
    SELECT
        ds.Date, tA.id
    FROM #tmpDateSequence as ds
        CROSS JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT a.id
            FROM #tableA as a
        )tA 




Date
id




2024-02-03
A


2024-02-04
A


2024-02-05
A


2024-02-06
A


2024-02-07
A


2024-02-08
A


2024-02-09
A


2024-02-03
B


2024-02-04
B


2024-02-05
B



Next step, is to get, for each id and date , the last num value
for the current date.
/* this returns, for each id, the last num till day X*/
    (SELECT TOP(1) a.num
        FROM #tableA as a
        WHERE s.id = a.id
            AND s.Date >= a.timestamp
        ORDER BY a.timestamp DESC
    )as n

Final step , to aggregate it.
SELECT s.Date, 
       SUM(ISNULL(n.num,0)) as sum_Num
FROM
(
    /*this generats all posible combinations of dates with ids*/
    SELECT
        ds.Date, tA.id
    FROM #tmpDateSequence as ds
        CROSS JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT a.id
            FROM #tableA as a
        )tA
)as s
OUTER APPLY  
/* this returns, for each id, the last num till day X*/
    (SELECT TOP(1) a.num
        FROM #tableA as a
        WHERE s.id = a.id
            AND s.Date >= a.timestamp
        ORDER BY a.timestamp DESC
    )as n
GROUP BY    
    s.Date
ORDER BY s.Date ASC

Output:



Date
sumNum




2024-02-03
0


2024-02-04
8


2024-02-05
8


2024-02-06
8


2024-02-07
14


2024-02-08
14


2024-02-09
14



dbfiddle
